# i can use codeigniter and my file gave the error of undefine variable:main_content

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]I make a variable main_content in main.php defination of this variable in my controller but it gave the error of undefine variable  main_content in mian.php

**layouts/main.php view file**

```
 //Add header
<?php $this->load->view('layouts/includes/header');     ?>
//Make a variable which dafine in controller
<?php     $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
//Add footer
<?php    $this->load->view('layouts/includes/footer');     ?>
```

**Controller calling the view**

```
/////This is my controller is

<?php
class product extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        /// variable name
         $data['name']='ali';
         //// Define main_content by Passing a View is 'new'

         $data['$main_content']='new';
         /// Gave the path of main page
         $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);``
    }
}




?>
```

[image: Screen Short of My page]

Comment: You have a syntax error. Take a look at `$data['$main_content']='new';` and I am sure you will see your misteak

Comment: so where is proofs of `$main_content` is defined? you wrote *I make a variable main_content in main.php defination of this variable in my controller* show us your controller then. anf in you have your controller somewhere else, then what is this file `main.php` ??? view? model?

Comment: @Alex He specified the details, but I cleaned it up to hopefully make it easier to see.

Comment: Do you think this statement `$data['$main_content']='new';` should read `$data['main_content']='new';`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I see. I think you can set your comment as answer then.

Comment: @MImran `$main` from your screenshot must be declared somewhere else in the view. The code which you provided does not show it. Show more code from main.php

Comment: @alex I thought so too but OP's screenshot proves otherwise, he does not know what he is chasing. Typographical error at it's finest

Comment: Yes i think it should read $data[main_content]='new'

Answer (score 0):

So, creating a $data[] for the view is very easy on Codeigniter.
I cannot understand what you trying to do but to get it working you need to do:

in `View` folder create a Subfolder "`layouts`" and "`product`":

The structure need to look like:

```
View/
---- product/
------------- index.php

---- layouts/
     ------------- main.php
     ---- includes/
     ------------ header.php
     ------------ footer.php
```

main.php content:

```
 //Add header
<?php $this->load->view('layouts/includes/header');     ?>
//Make a variable which dafine in controller
<?php     $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
//Add footer
<?php    $this->load->view('layouts/includes/footer');     ?>
```

index.php view:

```
<?php

var_dump($name);

?>
```

in your controller:

```
/////This is my controller is

<?php
class product extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        /// variable name
         $data['name'] = 'ali';
         //// Define main_content by Passing a View is 'new'

         $data['main_content'] = 'product/index';
         /// Gave the path of main page
         $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
    }
}




?>
```

Comment: You need to define `$data = array();` or `$data = [];`.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake making the first structure, i edited the question, now it should be fine !